# Reliable virtualization software for OS X?

Tags: osx, virtualization

I want to run Windows 7 virtual machine on my OS X laptop (late 2012 model with 8GB of memory) to use some simple Windows software from time to time. I don't want to use [bootcamp](http://www.apple.com/support/bootcamp/) to dual-boot. I have tried [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/), but it's really slow and not too stable.

I would appreciate snapshots and suspending, but reliability is the most important feature.

Answer (score 4):

The best hypervisor I've seen for OS X is **[Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/downloads/desktop/)**. On a Macbook Pro which has the [right hardware](http://ark.intel.com/products/virtualizationtechnology), it will have Intel VT-x and EPT support, giving you a *very* fast VM.

It does support snapshots and suspending, and it's rock-solid reliable.

I've used it to...

- Run Windows 7 and Windows 8.
- Run Windows-only apps (Windows version of Office, etc...).
- Run Windows-only games. (League of Legends before the Mac Client was released, ran at 60FPS on high settings on a Retina Macbook Pro)

Comment: I'll take a look into it.

Answer (score 1):

For about 3 years, I've used [VMWare Fusion](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion). It is amazing. I've always been a fan of VMWare's products because they have snapshots, suspending, etc. However, I was even more impressed when I installed Fusion on my Mac.

- Snapshots, suspending, etc. ([Fusion Feature Page](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/features))
- Supports Windows 7 (and every other version of Windows including 8.1, XP, etc.)
- My MacBook Pro has only 4 GB ram (OSX, from 2011)
- Windows inside the virtual machine is responsive
- OSX (host) is responsive
- It has NEVER crashed and I reboot Windows about once per month
- true integration, not just a guest OS running inside a host OS. Really impressed with the integration between OSX and Windows. I was used to using VMWare to run Windows inside Windows (for testing) but with Fusion it is really like having the best of both worlds. I have some apps which only run under Windows and use it for that.

They offer a free trial but I'm sure you will love it.*

- I know it sounds like I work for VMWare but I do not. I am just really, really happy with the quality and functionality of their software.